# Set a default header to each http client call

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I want to set a default header for every method in the UserHttpClient but I don`t want that every method is doing that, I want to do it in a general way.

The problem I see with the current implementation is, that when I call one method the _client gets disposed thus at the next call within a Http Request the _client is not initialized, as this happens within the constructor.

The UserHttpClient is registered via DI as per Http Request.

I also do not want to create a private/base method where I pass the _client and do the header addition there.

How would you solve that problem?

```
   public class UserHttpClient : IUserRemoteRepository
    {
        private readonly string baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["baseUrl"];
        private readonly string header = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userHeader"];

        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        public ServiceProductDataProvider(string toolSystemKeyHeader)
        {
            _client = new HttpClient();
            _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header, token);
        }

        public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetUsers(UserRequestDto dto)
        {
            using (_client)
            {              

                // do stuff
                var users = await _client.GetAsync("url here");

            }
        }

        public async Task<UserDto> GetUser(Guid userId)
        {
            using (_client)
            {              

                // do stuff
                var users = await _client.GetAsync("url here");

            }
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The class `UserHttpClient` has a member that is `IDisposable` (`private readonly HttpClient _client;`). That means that the `UserHttpClient` should also implement `IDisposable`:

```
public void Dispose() 
{
    _client.Dispose();
}
```

Then, the class/code that is using `UserHttpClient` is responsible for Disposing it after it's done with it. If the instance is injected, then the DI framework you use probably handles disposing it automatically at the end of the request. What's left for you then is to simply remove the `using` blocks from the implementation:

```
public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetUsers(UserRequestDto dto)
{
    // do stuff
    var users = await _client.GetAsync("url here");
}
```

---- EDIT ----

You could also work around the issue by *not* reusing the `HttpClient`:

```
private string _toolSystemKeyHeader;
public ServiceProductDataProvider(string toolSystemKeyHeader)
{
    _toolSystemKeyHeader = toolSystemKeyHeader
}
private HttpClient GetClientInstance()
{
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(header, _toolSystemKeyHeader); //?? in your original code, the toolSystemKeyHeader is not used, but I guess it is the token..?
    return _client;
}
```

And:

```
public async Task<List<UserDto>> GetUsers(UserRequestDto dto)
{
    using (var _client = GetClientInstance())
    {              
        // do stuff
        var users = await _client.GetAsync("url here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just that I did before I saw your post! Still thanks! but with the using I can be sure that in an error case the client gets disposed, but without using who guarantees me that?

Comment: The DI framework, most likely. But that you'd have to find out from its documentation.

Comment: I am inheritiing now from HttpClient. That seems best to me for the DI wiring up per http request doing the UserHttp call.